# The array control is messed up

Tags: modifiers

[[image: array mess]]

So i have modeled a bill here [see pic] and i want to rotate it with an empty object like every other tutorial you see on youtube...
But there, DANG!
It doesn't transform as expected!
It squishes and distorts for every iteration you add, its frustrating
Other than starting completely on a basic cube, i followed hoards of youtube tuts that always starts with the cube.
Do i have to start at a cube and forget about the dollar bill?
please help. :(

Comment: If you could upload your .blend file to [this website](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), it would help greatly.

Comment: ok, where is the upload button?

Comment: Click in the big box in the middle of the screen to select your file, then click the orange upload button.

Comment: dude there's a problem with that uploader too

Comment: is that uploader in test phase still?

Comment: No. I honestly have no idea what the problem you are facing is now.

Comment: Make sure both your objects have applied scale and rotation. Ctrl + A > Apply Scale and Alt + R to clear rotation.

Comment: ok ill try that :)

Comment: thanks, the squishing  was fixed now, but the scale is still magnified

Comment: ah! ok got it :D you have to fix the scale for the empty as well